How to configure sqlfluff to lint the Model Configuration
I'm trying to configure sqlfluff to lint my models, but I don't seem to find any custom configuration or any source that explain how to lint the configuration box of the models.
With that I'm referring to, for example:
{{
    config(
        materialized='view',
        incremental_strategy='delete+insert',
        unique_key='DATE',
        schema='RAW_DATA',
        alias='ALL_COST'
    )
}}



It would be useful to see your sqlfluff config file

I asked the same question in the SQLfluff slack some time ago - I can't find the answer because they the free version of slack with short history.
The answer i got was that it is not possible at the current time to because the code in the config block is in fact Python.
